# Access control: allow rewritten urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Using RewriteRule, I have http://example.com/login point to http://example.com/login.php.

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /login.php [L]
```

I also have the access control rules to allow only certain files:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

But then http://example.com/login gives a 403 error.
Is there a way to allow "rewritten" urls to allow access by default without specifying an additional rule?

Comment: Can you show your rewrite rules in question

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak your `FilesMatch` directive to allow certain URI patterns:

```
<FilesMatch "^login/?$|\.(htm|html|css|js|php)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

This will allow `http://example.com/login`.